# How to manage AsyncTasks priority?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have master view with images within every item. I've implemented lazy image fetching as in this example [Displaying Bitmaps Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DisplayingBitmaps). When I click item detail view appears. Data for detail view is also downloading from internet.

The problem is when I go to detail view while images in master view are just start downloading then DetailAsyncTask (which download necessary data in detail view) starts only after ImageFetchingTask of master view is done.

So my question is what is best approach in order for detail view to start its DetailAsyncTask immediately? Cancelling ImageFetchingTask when detail view creates or to set higher priority to its DetailAsyncTask or something else?

Comment: Are you using the same method as in the example to schedule the `AsyncTask`s (the example uses a custom dual thread executor without priority queueing). Note that (a) [thread priority in java is basically useless](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority.shtml) and (b) the fetcher tasks spend most of their time blocking for IO (downloading the image) and not consuming CPU so stepping up the priority doesn't help (but you can still modify the task queue order).

Comment: @dhke Yes, I actually copy-past classes from example and modifying it for my need. I'm not so good in threads and not sure that I can modify the task queue order by myself. Can you please share some examples or ideas how to achieve this?